# erlang embedded into C

Tags: c, erlang

I'm looking to embed the Erlang VM into C code... Im familiar with ports, linkedin drivers, etc. 
I want the C program to start the Erlang VM, and then pass messages to Erlang processes, and have those pass messages back to C code. I dont want the erlang VM to be the one that starts first and then invokes C code occasionally. I have my reasons.
I know that this negatively affects stability guarantees given by Erlang, meaning that when the master C code crashes it will taken down the Erlang VM also, since they're running in the same process. Im willing to live with those occurrences...

is this even possible?

Comment: +1 to balance downvote without a comment. This seems like a reasonable question, of interest to erlang developers.

Comment: Important is also the why you want to do this? If you only say "you have your reasons" its unlikely to get most out of the answers.  I mean sure it is possible, since you have got the source.  But if it makes sense is another question.  Also the how to interact with your C code changes the way you want to integrate this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only sane way to do this is to load the C code from the Erlang VM, not vice versa.

It's not possible out of the box, but since you have access to the Erlang source it's clearly possible to do whatever you want if you're willing to spend a lot of time modifying the code. It's not a good use of your time to go down this path.

Comment: yeah I kind of figured that last night... thanks for the confirmation though. it seems that erlang really is the ultimate controller, no choice but to have everything else started by it ;)).   I heart erlang ;))

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way would be to just launch it as a separate process, and then use stdin and stdout to communicate. Just reading the docs of whatever platform you're targeting will let you know how to do that.

Comment: Im familiar with that approach... domain sockets are also an alternative,or using memory maped files directly... my goal though is to share the same memory space between the custom C code and the Erlang VM itself... the OS kernel would never be touched for the communication i/o between the erlang and C code, no context switching, etc...